# No NETSH WLAN context in Server 2008 Core install?

Tags: netsh, wlan, windows-server-core

I installed Windows Server 2008 Core on a netbook and I'm trying to set it up as a wireless router. Took forever to find the right wifi drivers...

But now I'm running into this problem that there appears to be no wlan context in NETSH for Server 2008 Core. Is this correct? Is there a role or service I need to install first?

So far there appears to be no way to connect to a wireless network, much less create a hosted network, using the netsh interface context.

I've spent the last 40 minutes scouring the internet trying to find more information with no success. I'm *this* close to putting a Linux router on it - though from the looks of it I'd run into the same problem and be stuck having to fork out the dough for a wifi access point.

:Edit:
This is Server 2008, *NOT* 2008r2. I'm running it on a netbook in a production environment in a home office. Right now it only serves DNS and DHCP, but I want to eventually use it to replace the wifi router entirely. This consolidates hardware and management onto a platform with a built-in battery backup with far more management features than standard linux-based router distributions provide.

While this is primarily a learning project, it is a high priority production project as well since the wifi router appears to be failing. And since my time is far cheaper right now than a new router and I have the hardware and the software, this is the best replacement plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows server has wireless turned off by default.  You have to add the feature under the server manager.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg597292.aspx

Comment: Since I'm using server 2008 Core, server manager isn't exactly an option. I've tried using the command prompt, but the exact service name is required to use ocsetup and I'm unable to find any documentation on the Wireless LAN Service feature when using a command prompt, much less when using server Core.

Comment: @Thomas You could install it with PowerShell, or better yet use RSAT from your own workstation.

Comment: All workstations in this location run Windows 8, which admin tools don't talk nice with Server 2008. Server 2008 does not have PowerShell and the only installation instructions for it I've been able to find are a hack.